# FadeIn Action in LibGDX not working correctly

Tags: libgdx, fadein, actor, fadeout

Please, help me. I try:

```
actor.addAction(Actions.fadeOut(1.5f));
```

I get:
All my Stage is fading out.

So, my question is why fading out not only one actor, for which I applied fadeOut action, but all my Stage (or at least some other actors)?

My render:

```
@Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.draw();
        stage.act();
    }
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but `glClearColor` expects normalized colors between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any actor class of your own must apply its own color to the batch. This is unnecessary with things like BitmapFont and Sprite, which pass colored vertices directly to the batch, but any actor that calls `batch.draw` will need to first pass a color, even if it's `Color.WHITE`, but generally you will want to pass `getColor()` to the batch.

This is because there is no guarantee of what color has been left in the batch from any previously drawn actors.

Also, if your actors are in groups and you want them to fade with their parent, then they should take parent alpha into account:

```
Color color = getColor();
batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * parentAlpha);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your actor's implementation of draw() is not changing the batch's color

Comment: `@Override
        public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
            batch.draw(cardTexture, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
            super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
        }`

Comment: are you directly extending actor? Then you can delete super.draw(batch,parentalpha);

otherwise, show me that method.

Comment: There isn't a "contract" in `actor.draw` that you must leave the batch color white. Many of LibGDX's built-in widgets leave the batch with any old arbitrary color. Instead, you need to be aware when subclassing Actor that you cannot assume the batch passed into `actor.draw` has a color of `WHITE`.